# Telosys Timestamp Generation Date problem (missing nanosecond precision)

Tags: date, jpa, timestamp, telosys

Telosys generates timestamp columns like that:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="AKT_TS")
private Date aktTs;
```

Unfortunately Date does only have millisecond precision, not nanosecond (but the DB has of course).
Example:

- Date (Java): 2020-12-03T16:28:58.302+**0000**
- DB: 2020-12-03 17:28:58.302**339**

Is there an easy way to force telosys to generate LocalDateTime (or java.sql.Timestamp), so that the whole precision can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the model entity file use the '**timestamp**' type  with '**@SqlType**'

'@SqlType' switches to 'java.sql.*' types (Time, Timestamp, Blob, etc) if possible

Example :

Entity file :

```
 fieldName : timestamp { @SqlType } ;
```

Generated code :

```
  @Column(name="fieldName")
  private Timestamp  fieldName    ;
```

Comment: I use XxxJpaRecord_java.vm. What do I have to change in the template, or what do you mean?

Comment: There is nothing to change in the templates (Velocity .vm files). 
The change is to do in your entity definition in the DSL model (.entity file). 
But perhaps you're using a "database model" (.dbrep file), in this case select the type "Timestamp (sql)" for your attribute in the model editor (Eclipse plugin).

Comment: Yes I use the database model. Unfortunetaly I have many tables with many colums. Changing with the model editor would not be efficient. What I need is a global configuration / change.
I think in meantime generating date for TIMESTAMP is not a good choice at all and should be switched in general.

Comment: A ".dbrep" file is just an XML file so you can simply use "Find/Replace" with your favorite editor to change all the date types in the file.   Find : [javaType="java.util.Date"] and Replace with : [javaType="java.sql.Timestamp"]

Comment: I'm new to Telosys and don't see any `.dbrep` files in my `TelosysTools` folder. How do I change what type Telosys maps to? I would prefer an `OffsetDateTime` for my POJOs.