# Telosys Type Overriding - `timestamp` -> `OffsetDateTime`

Tags: java, telosys

My entities contain a `timestamp` attribute that is getting converted to a `LocalDateTime` as [the docs specify](https://doc.telosys.org/target-languages/java#types-conversion). However, I would like to convert the `timestamp` into an `OffsetDateTime`. Is there any way to override the default conversion behavior?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591822/telosys-timestamp-generation-date-problem-missing-nanosecond-precision) mentions a .dbrep, but I don't have such a file in my project.

Comment: ".dbrep" is an old model file format that no longer exists since version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the default conversion behavior,
but you can change the type in the templates (.vm files) using Velocity language.

1. If you want to convert the type systematically (for all attributes of all entities) you can proceed like these:

> #if ( $attribute.neutralType == 'timestamp' )
> #set ($mytype = 'OffsetDateTime')
> #else
> #set ($mytype = $attribute.simpleType )
> #end

if this operation must be repeated in several templates you can define a macro

2. If you want to force the conversion only for some attributes :

- in the model (".entity") add a tag to the concerned attributes :

> myField : timestamp { **#tagetType**(OffsetDateTime) } ;

- use this tag value in the templates (and keep the standard type as default value)

> $attribute.tagValue( '**targetType**', $attribute.simpleType )

In both cases, do not forget to import 'java.time.OffsetDateTime'

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking here in the future, I ended up going with the answer @Igu suggested (#1) - which isn't necessarily for all attributes of all entities. (Unless I'm missing how it should be applied).

The macro looked like:

```
#macro( typeFor $attribute )
#if ( $attribute.neutralType == 'timestamp' )OffsetDateTime#else$attribute.simpleType#end
#end
```

Unfortunately, the formatting seems to be necessary in order to not add extra newlines or spaces in the generated `.java` file. I added this macro definition to a common `#parse` file and was able to use it across Models & DTOs alike.

Invoking the macro looks like this:

```
#foreach( $attribute in $entity.nonKeyAttributes )
$jpa.fieldAnnotations(2, $attribute)
  private #typeFor( $attribute ) $attribute.name#if($attribute.hasInitialValue()) = ${attribute.initialValue}#end;
#end
```